# Salesforce SAP Integration

Tags: apex, integration, soap

I have created a APEX class from WSDL ( WSDL provided by SAP ). Need Help in calling this APEX class in Salesforce. This is a Demo Flight Object. When I pass Flight Number and Name, it will return Flight information.

Below is the Apex Class ( Generated From WSDL)

```
public class ramanWsToRfc {

    public class Flight_element {
        public String Carrid;
        public String FlightName;
        public String Connid;
        public String Date_x;
        public String ArpFrom;
        public String CityFrom;
        public String ArpTo;
        public String CityTo;
        private String[] Carrid_type_info = new String[]{'Carrid','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] FlightName_type_info = new String[]{'FlightName','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Connid_type_info = new String[]{'Connid','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] Date_x_type_info = new String[]{'Date','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] ArpFrom_type_info = new String[]{'ArpFrom','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] CityFrom_type_info = new String[]{'CityFrom','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] ArpTo_type_info = new String[]{'ArpTo','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] CityTo_type_info = new String[]{'CityTo','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Carrid','FlightName','Connid','Date_x','ArpFrom','CityFrom','ArpTo','CityTo'};
    }
    public class Dt_Flight_Res_Ib {
        public ramanWsToRfc.Flight_element Flight;
        private String[] Flight_type_info = new String[]{'Flight','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Flight'};
    }
    public class Dt_Flight_Req_Ob {
        public ramanWsToRfc.Flight_element Flight;
        private String[] Flight_type_info = new String[]{'Flight','urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC','false','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Flight'};
    }
    public class Si_Flight_ObPort {
        public String endpoint_x = '**********************';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC', 'ramanWsToRfc'};
        public ramanWsToRfc.Flight_element Si_Flight_Ob(ramanWsToRfc.Flight_element Flight) {
            ramanWsToRfc.Dt_Flight_Req_Ob request_x = new ramanWsToRfc.Dt_Flight_Req_Ob();
            request_x.Flight = Flight;
            ramanWsToRfc.Dt_Flight_Res_Ib response_x;
            Map<String, ramanWsToRfc.Dt_Flight_Res_Ib> response_map_x = new Map<String, ramanWsToRfc.Dt_Flight_Res_Ib>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1',
              'urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',
              'Mt_Flight_Req_Ob',
              'urn:Raman_Ws_To_RFC',
              'Mt_Flight_Res_Ib',
              'ramanWsToRfc.Dt_Flight_Res_Ib'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.Flight;
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me on, how to call this ?